# How to set the width of a pointer in c?

Tags: c, pointers

I have a 1D array which has been dynamically allocated, and i want to point a double pointer (**ptr) to it, and then treat ptr as a 2D array, but for that the width of the 2D array should be set, is there any way to do this. For example if I have an array of dimensions 80 which i want to treat as a 8*10 2D array, such that ((*ptr)+1) will move by 10 units. I know that I can manually use it as arr[i*row + j], but I would prefer doing it the other way is possible. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: `Type a[80]; Type (*b)[10] = (Type (*)[10])a;` Using `b[i][j]`.

Comment: Could i replace the 10 with a variable such as col? (thanks for the answer btw).

Comment: The terms 'width' and 'double' are ambiguous in this question. In the context of the C language, they are normally understood to have different meaning than you have intended here. It is perhaps clear in the question what you mean, but the title on its own is misleading.

Comment: @KarthikR It is possible as VLA since C99.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY : Post an answer; that is not an appropriate _comment_.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY VLAs are made optional in C11, so it's "may be possible depending on your compiler".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reinterpret a one-dimensional array as a two-dimensional array using a pointer:

```
Type a[80];
Type (*b)[10] = (Type (*)[10])a;//or simply (void*)a. b is pointer to Type[10]
```

Using `b[i][j]`

note: 
Double pointers (like as `**ptr`) are basically mistakes.
Generally the array is not an array of pointers.

Also `int col = 10; Type (*b)[col] = (Type (*)[col])a;` is possible as VLA(Variable Length Array) since C99 (Options for c11).

Answer (score 1):

You never point a `TYPE**` at anything but a `TYPE*` object. You don't have any `TYPE*` objects. An array of `TYPE` isn't one. You may allocate an array of `TYPE*` *in addition to* an array of `TYPE` and arrange for each element of the former to point at the relevant element of the latter.

```
TYPE* elements = malloc (N_rows * N_cols * sizeof(TYPE));
TYPE** rows = malloc (N_rows * sizeof(TYPE*));
for (i = 0; i < N_rows; ++i) 
  rows[i] = elements + N_cols * i;
```

This is however rather inefficient and inconvenient. If one of your dimensions is a compile-time constant, or you can use VLAs, there is a way to do it without any double-dereferencing (detailed in the other answer so I won't repeat it).